# Forward declaration error in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, forward-declaration

I have a class defined in a hpp file which I'm trying to use in another header, so I made a forward declaration to it (I only want to use it by reference as a function parameter). For some reason I keep getting a compile error because of it. I can't figure out why it's not working. Here are my codes:

```
//something.hpp:
class MyClass;
void someFunction (MyClass& mc);
...

//something.cpp:
#include "MyClass.hpp"
void someFunction (MyClass& mc) {...}
...

//MyClass.hpp:
class MyClass {
    const char* myText;
public:
    MyClass (const char* text) : myText(text) {}
};

//main.cpp:
int main () {
    ...
    someFunction (MyClass ("some text here"));
    ...
}
```

And I get an error from main() which says:

```
'<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const char [15]' to 'MyClass'
Source or target has incomplete type
```

If I understand it right, it means that the compiler doesn't find the definition of MyClass, only the predeclaration of it (even though I included MyClass.hpp in something.cpp), that's why it says it's incomplete. What did I miss here?

Comment: You need to `#include "MyClass.hpp"` in `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

```
void someFunction (MyClass& mc);
```

is accepting a non-const reference to a `MyClass` instance.

You are not allowed to pass a temporary to such a function.

The code should be

```
 #include "MyClass.hpp"
 ...
 int main() {
     MyClass m("some text here");
     someFunction(m);
 }
```

or alternatively you need to accept a const reference.

```
void someFunction (const MyClass& mc);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the problem is related to the forward declaration, but rather that you cannot pass a temporary to a function taking a reference as argument. In fact, if you put all your definitions in a single file, it still doesn't compile. On the other hand, if you replace the code of the main with the following, it will compile:

```
int main() {
    MyClass mc("Some text here");
    someFunction(mc); 
}
```